# How to perform git diff --name-status origin/master...HEAD in the LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am using LibGit2Sharp. How can I invoke the git `diff` command with the following parameters?

```
git diff --name-status origin/master...HEAD
```

I know, that `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B`.

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, please feel free to edit it further or roll it back to the previous version.

Comment: @JDB Thanks for editing, but I found the solution(answer below).

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! It's users like you that make Stack Overflow such an awesome resource for other developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to do this. You can do it in this way:

1) Get two commits common ancestor.

2) Get diff between trees.

```
var baseCommit = repo.ObjectDatabase.FindMergeBase(repo.Branches["origin/master"].Tip, repo.Head.Tip);
var diff = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(baseCommit.Tree, repo.Head.Tip.Tree);
```